# How to parse very large json array with Moshi in Android?

Tags: android, moshi

I have a very large `json` file containing words from a specific language, from the dictionary. This file has more than 348 000+ words. Each object has different properties.

Here is an example of the `json` array:

```
[
...
{"id":"57414","form":"t'est","formNoAccent":"test","formUtf8General":"test","reverse":"tset","number":null,"description":"","noAccent":"0","consistentAccent":"1","frequency":"0.98","hyphenations":null,"pronunciations":null,"stopWord":"0","compound":"0","modelType":"N","modelNumber":"1","restriction":"","staleParadigm":"0","notes":"","hasApheresis":"0","hasApocope":"1","createDate":"1196798482","modDate":"1637245287"},
{"id":"57415","form":"ț'est","formNoAccent":"țest","formUtf8General":"țest","reverse":"tseț","number":null,"description":"","noAccent":"0","consistentAccent":"1","frequency":"0.93","hyphenations":null,"pronunciations":null,"stopWord":"0","compound":"0","modelType":"N","modelNumber":"24","restriction":"","staleParadigm":"0","notes":"","hasApheresis":"0","hasApocope":"1","createDate":"1196798482","modDate":"1637245213"},
...
]
```

I want to add these entries inside `Room` and have them persist there. The problem I am facing right now is that I haven't done anything similar to this and I am getting `out of memory` when I try to transform everything into a list of objects using `Moshi`.

The solution would be to load every item separately but I don't think it will be possible.

Until now, it looks like this:

```
        val archive = context.assets.open("table_lexeme.zip")
        val destination = File.createTempFile("table_lexeme", ".zip")
        val jsonFile = File.createTempFile("lexeme", ".json")

        archive.use {
            destination.writeBytes(it.readBytes())
        }

        ZipFile(destination).use { zip ->
            zip.entries().asSequence().forEach { zipEntry ->
                if (zipEntry.name == "dex_table_lexeme.json") {
                    zip.getInputStream(zipEntry).use { inputStream ->
                        val bos = BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(jsonFile))
                        val bytesIn = ByteArray(BUFFER_SIZE)
                        var read: Int
                        while (inputStream.read(bytesIn).also { read = it } != -1) {
                            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read)
                        }
                        bos.close()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val jsonReader = JsonReader(InputStreamReader(jsonFile.inputStream(), Charsets.UTF_8))
        jsonReader.beginArray()
```

Comment: "I want to add these entries inside Room and have them persist there" -- since this data is packaged as an asset, why are you messing with a ZIP file and JSON? Room supports packaged databases as assets, so you could ship the actual SQLite database rather than JSON. That will be *much* faster to set up for the user than will be importing hundreds of thousands of rows.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you know any tool I can use to package the database?

Comment: I would use Room itself to create the empty database. From there, you have countless SQLite options for filling in data. I have used Ruby scripts and Kotlin command-line programs, for example. Or, there are GUI tools like [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). After that, you put the database in `assets` and roll from there. See https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.9/PackagedFTS for an example app that uses a packaged database (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Room), FWIW).

Comment: I remembered why I am not doing this. The database I have is in Mysql/MariaDB, exporting the tables I need as JSON is the most accurate way I can use it without changing the script to be compatible with SqLite3

Comment: That does not stop you from creating the SQLite database from that JSON on your development machine.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Managed to find a python script well written that supports large JSON files, probably I will wait a few hours to finish importing it. Already running for 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal solution would be to switch to a streaming JSON parser, so your whole data set is not loaded into RAM at once. `JsonReader` in the Android SDK works this way, and Gson has a streaming mode. I do not recall Moshi offering this, but I haven't looked for that recently.

The realistic solution is to not package JSON. Importing those will be slow, even if you use transaction batches (e.g., insert 100 rows in a batch). You are packaging your data as an asset, so you will be better off (IMHO) generating the SQLite database on your development machine and packaging it. Room has built-in support to copy a packaged database from an asset and put it into position for use. While your database file is going to be large, it will be faster to copy it than to create it on the fly with imported data.